# want to show overflow hidden for one image but not for other

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have three images, two out of them I want to overflow hidden and for the third one I want to show overflow.

[image]

Expected Outcome:

[image]

This is my code for this part

```
<div class="image-container">
      <div class="inner">
        <picture>
          <source srcset="./images/illustration-woman-online-mobile.svg" media="(max-width: 890px)">
          <img class="main-img" src="./images/illustration-woman-online-desktop.svg" alt="">
        </picture>
        <picture>
          <source srcset="./images/bg-pattern-mobile.svg" media="(max-width: 890px)">
          <img class="sec-img" src="./images/bg-pattern-desktop.svg" alt="">
        </picture>
      </div>
      <div class="outer">
        <img class="box" src="./images/illustration-box-desktop.svg" alt="">
      </div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
.image-container {
  position: relative;
  padding: 50px 50px 50px 0;
  margin-left: -80px;
  z-index: 0;
}

.inner {
  overflow: hidden;
}

.sec-img {
  position: absolute;
  top: -300px;
  left: -500px;
  z-index: -1;
}

.box {
  position: absolute;
  display: block;
  top: 190px;
  left: -30px;
}
```

Github repo:
https://github.com/rishipurwar1/faq-accordion-card-main
Live URL: https://faq-accordion-card-git.netlify.app/
Please anyone help me with this

Comment: just move the 3rd img (which should be visible) from the overflow hidden container

Comment: If you see my code, I seperate the box imag(3rd) from the container. Please check github repo

Comment: sorry I was checking out the URL. In that case, I'd move margin-left from the image-container to the picture elements in the inner and then on the outer element I'd add position: absolute; top: 0; left: -80px;

Comment: What I understand from your comment is remove margin left from the image container and then add that margin to the element in the inner div and in the outer div add position absolute. Am i right?

Comment: yes. you can try it out on your own as well :D